# Should I force an upgrade of packages gjs & libgjs0g

Tags: 22.04

Packages gjs & libgjs0g have been shown as "not to upgrade" for weeks when e.g. sudo apt autoremove. Should I force an upgrade on them in Terminal?
PS running 22.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not force an upgrade.

See https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/phased-updates.html

Summary of that page: Users have reported problems with the gjs update, so it has been paused while the developers sort it out.

It's GOOD that the problems were found before the update reached you.

When fixed, the update will occur normally and automatically. You don't need to take any special action at all. Just be patient.